# how to open file within while loop that is dependant on information not yet declared?

Tags: c, file, loops, fopen

I am attempting to open a file that will only be known once it has been created within a directory, however the FILE *infile (etc, etc..) function does not work in this scenario as "infile" has not previously been delcared. I can't work out how to declare this before the loop so that it gets the current file that is being iterated at that time.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <sys/inotify.h>
    #include <openssl/sha.h>

    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
            int result;
            int fd;
            int wd;
            unsigned char c[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
            int i;
            //FILE *inFile = fopen (filename, "rb"); //I'm aware this would usually
                                                     //be declared here              
            SHA512_CTX mdContext;
            int bytes;
            unsigned char data[1024];
            const int event_size = sizeof(struct inotify_event);
            const int buf_len = 1024 * (event_size + FILENAME_MAX);


            fd = inotify_init();

            if (fd < 0) {
              perror("inotify_init");
            }

            wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/home/joe/Documents", IN_CREATE);

            while (1) {
              char buff[buf_len];
              char target[FILENAME_MAX];
              int no_of_events, count = 0;

              no_of_events = read (fd, buff, buf_len);
              while (count < no_of_events) {
                struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&buff[count];
                if (event->len) {
                  if (event->mask & IN_CREATE)
                  if(!(event->mask & IN_ISDIR)) {
                    printf("The file %s has been created\n", event->name);

                    //FILE *infile = fopen (filename, "rb");  //issue arises here 
                                                              //when not commented
                    SHA512_Init (&mdContext);
                    while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, filename)) != 0)
                        SHA512_Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);
                    SHA512_Final (c,&mdContext);
                    for(i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) printf("%02x", c[i]);
                    printf (" %s\n", event->name);
                    fclose (filename);
                    return 0;
                    fflush(stdout);
                  }
                }
                count += event_size + event->len;
              }
            }
            return 0;
    }
```

I'm trying to work out the issue hence the comments and also undeclared "filename".

Comment: Aside: note that `fread (data, 1, 1024, filename)` should be `fread (data, 1, 1024, infile)` and there should have been a compiler warning.

Comment: `while (count < no_of_events)` How about a`for()` loop?

Comment: *Why* can't you open the file at `//issue arises here when not commented`, if you define `char filename[] = "/home/joe/Documents";`? What is the issue that arises?

Comment: Do you really mean to have a `return` in your middle `while` loop?  That will return from the function, and since the function in question here is `main`, that will furthermore exit the program.  If indeed you do want to do that, then note, too, that the `fflush()` call immediately following the `return` statement will never be executed (though it's also unneeded under the circumstances).

Comment: John - I was in the process of integrating the hash function into the iteration - I must have missed that! Unfortunately 'fopen' returns a segmentation fault now (after amending to the below answer) as it seems to think that the new file (its name defined by 'event->name') does not exist, when it clearly does! arhhh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the file that you want to open is stored in `event->name`.  That's what you want to pass to `fopen`.  Also, you want to pass `infile` to both `fread` and `fclose`.

```
FILE *infile = fopen (event->name, "rb");                   // event->name is the filename
SHA512_Init (&mdContext);
while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, infile )) != 0)       // read from infile
    SHA512_Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);
SHA512_Final (c,&mdContext);
for(i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) printf("%02x", c[i]);
printf (" %s\n", event->name);
fclose (infile);                                            // close infile
```